# compiling PointViewer with a makefile on NITE and OpenNI

Tags: c++, compilation, linker-errors, glut, openni

I'm currently on schedule with kinect openNi and NITE.
In fact I detect the hand position eg whether the hand is over your head or not? For this I need to change the PointViewer of NITE.

However, I can not compile when I modify the code.

In fact when I do a make being in the file PointViewer, if there are errors, the compiler reports them all to me but when I close to correct, I obtien undefined reference errors with the bookstore actually Glut it's like he was not included, whereas for me it is because before the PointViewer modified the code worked.

I already installed freeglut3-dev and included the libraries  and .
The problem occurs when making the link as you said.
Is there any compiler options for the linkage to succeed?
How to add compiler options in the makefile so it can find where is the GLU library?

Do you have an idea of what this might be?

Here I obtien lce:

```
g++ -o ../Bin/x64-Release/Sample-PointViewer ./x64-Release/main.o ./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o ./x64-Release/signal_catch.o  -L../Bin/x64-Release -lglut -lOpenNI -lXnVNite_1_5_2
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glutDisplay(): error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glutDisplay(): error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glutDisplay(): error: undefined reference to 'glPushMatrix'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glutDisplay(): error: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glutDisplay(): error: undefined reference to 'glOrtho'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glutDisplay(): error: undefined reference to 'glDisable'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glInit(int*, char**): error: undefined reference to 'glDisable'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glInit(int*, char**): error: undefined reference to 'glEnable'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glInit(int*, char**): error: undefined reference to 'glEnableClientState'
./x64-Release/main.o:main.cpp:function glInit(int*, char**): error: undefined reference to 'glDisableClientState'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function initTexture(void**, int&, int&): error: undefined reference to 'glGenTextures'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function initTexture(void**, int&, int&): error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function initTexture(void**, int&, int&): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameteri'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function initTexture(void**, int&, int&): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameteri'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawRectangle(float, float, float, float): error: undefined reference to 'glVertexPointer'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawRectangle(float, float, float, float): error: undefined reference to 'glDrawArrays'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawRectangle(float, float, float, float): error: undefined reference to 'glFlush'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawTexture(float, float, float, float): error: undefined reference to 'glEnableClientState'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawTexture(float, float, float, float): error: undefined reference to 'glTexCoordPointer'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawDepthMap(xn::DepthMetaData const&): error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawDepthMap(xn::DepthMetaData const&): error: undefined reference to 'glTexImage2D'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawDepthMap(xn::DepthMetaData const&): error: undefined reference to 'glColor4f'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawDepthMap(xn::DepthMetaData const&): error: undefined reference to 'glEnable'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawFrameID(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'glColor4f'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawFrameID(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'glRasterPos2i'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function XnVPointDrawer::Draw() const: error: undefined reference to 'glColor4f'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function XnVPointDrawer::Draw() const: error: undefined reference to 'glPointSize'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function XnVPointDrawer::Draw() const: error: undefined reference to 'glVertexPointer'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function XnVPointDrawer::Draw() const: error: undefined reference to 'glDrawArrays'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function XnVPointDrawer::Draw() const: error: undefined reference to 'glColor4f'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function XnVPointDrawer::Draw() const: error: undefined reference to 'glPointSize'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function XnVPointDrawer::Draw() const: error: undefined reference to 'glDrawArrays'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function XnVPointDrawer::Draw() const: error: undefined reference to 'glFlush'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function PrintSessionState(SessionState): error: undefined reference to 'glRasterPos2i'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function PrintSessionState(SessionState): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_create'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function PrintSessionState(SessionState): error: undefined reference to 'pthread_join'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawTexture(float, float, float, float): error: undefined reference to 'glDisableClientState'
./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o:PointDrawer.cpp:function DrawDepthMap(xn::DepthMetaData const&): error: undefined reference to 'glDisable'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../Bin/x64-Release/Sample-PointViewer] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some libraries to the link process. Start with adding -lGL -lpthread. (glClear is defined in libGL.so and the pthread ones are in libpthread.so. This is on Linux - you may need to install freeglut3-dev package on Ubuntu to get libGL.)

Comment: Thank your for answers.
I already installed freeglut3-dev and included the libraries <GLUT/glut.h> and <GL/glut.h>.
The problem occurs when making the link as you said.
Is there any compiler options for the linkage to succeed?
How to add compiler options in the makefile so it can find where is the GLU library?

Comment: You will need to locate the link step in the Makefile (the one which does  `code g++ -o ../Bin/x64-Release/Sample-PointViewer ./x64-Release/main.o ./x64-Release/PointDrawer.o ./x64-Release/signal_catch.o  -L../Bin/x64-Release -lglut -lOpenNI -lXnVNite_1_5_2` - and then add either of -lGL -lpthread or -framework GL -pthread depending on whether you use Ubuntu or Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The first errors look GL/GLUT related. Make sure you've got the include and library paths properly setup.

I've just compiled the sample on osx using Qt Creator, but removed opengles.cpp from the project since it was looking for a library I couldn't find on my system.
If it helps, here's my Qt Console app project file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2012-08-01T01:22:11
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = NitePointViewer
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/ni
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/nite
LIBS += /usr/lib/libXnCore.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libXnDDK.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libXnDeviceFile.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libXnDeviceSensorV2.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libXnFormats.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libXnVCNITE_1_5_2.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libXnVNite_1_5_2.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libnimMockNodes.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libnimRecorder.dylib
LIBS += /usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib
LIBS += -framework OpenGL
LIBS += -framework GLUT
LIBS += Libs/glut64.lib

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    signal_catch.cpp \
    PointDrawer.cpp \
    kbhit.cpp

HEADERS += \
    GL/wglext.h \
    GL/glut.h \
    GL/glext.h \
    GL/gl.h \
    GLES/gl.h \
    GLES/gl_1_0.h \
    GLES/egltypes.h \
    GLES/egl.h \
    GLES/egl_1_0.h \
    glh/glh_text.h \
    glh/glh_obs.h \
    glh/glh_mipmaps.h \
    glh/glh_linear.h \
    glh/glh_interactors.h \
    glh/glh_glut2.h \
    glh/glh_glut.h \
    glh/glh_glut_text.h \
    glh/glh_glut_replay.h \
    glh/glh_glut_callfunc.h \
    glh/glh_genext.h \
    glh/glh_extensions.h \
    glh/glh_cube_map.h \
    glh/glh_convenience.h \
    glh/glh_array.h \
    signal_catch.h \
    PointDrawer.h \
    opengles.h \
    kbhit.h
```

and the generated Makefile:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: NitePointViewer
# Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.7.4) on: Wed Aug 1 01:50:26 2012
# Project:  NitePointViewer.pro
# Template: app
# Command: /Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/bin/qmake -spec ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/macx-g++ -o Makefile NitePointViewer.pro
#############################################################################

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/QtCore -I../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include -I/usr/include/ni -I/usr/include/nite -I. -F/Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -F/Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -L/Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib /usr/lib/libXnCore.dylib /usr/lib/libXnDDK.dylib /usr/lib/libXnDeviceFile.dylib /usr/lib/libXnDeviceSensorV2.dylib /usr/lib/libXnFormats.dylib /usr/lib/libXnVCNITE_1_5_2.dylib /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.dylib /usr/lib/libXnVNite_1_5_2.dylib /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib /usr/lib/libnimMockNodes.dylib /usr/lib/libnimRecorder.dylib /usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT Libs/glut64.lib -framework QtCore 
AR            = ar cq
RANLIB        = ranlib -s
QMAKE         = /Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/bin/qmake
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
STRIP         = 
INSTALL_FILE  = $(COPY_FILE)
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(COPY_FILE)
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.4

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = ./

####### Files

SOURCES       = main.cpp \
        signal_catch.cpp \
        PointDrawer.cpp \
        kbhit.cpp 
OBJECTS       = main.o \
        signal_catch.o \
        PointDrawer.o \
        kbhit.o
DIST          = ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/mac.conf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/mac-g++.conf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/modules/qt_webkit_version.pri \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/dwarf2.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/debug.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/default_post.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/x86_64.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/objective_c.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/rez.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf \
        NitePointViewer.pro
QMAKE_TARGET  = NitePointViewer
DESTDIR       = 
TARGET        = NitePointViewer

####### Custom Compiler Variables
QMAKE_COMP_QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS = -pipe \
        -g \
        -gdwarf-2 \
        -arch \
        x86_64 \
        -Xarch_x86_64 \
        -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 \
        -Wall \
        -W


first: all
####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp .cc .cxx .C

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cxx.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.C.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

####### Build rules

all: Makefile $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJECTS)  
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)

Makefile: NitePointViewer.pro  ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/macx-g++/qmake.conf ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/mac.conf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/mac-g++.conf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/modules/qt_webkit_version.pri \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/dwarf2.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/debug.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/default_post.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/x86_64.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/objective_c.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/rez.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf
    $(QMAKE) -spec ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/macx-g++ -o Makefile NitePointViewer.pro
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/unix.conf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/mac.conf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/common/mac-g++.conf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/modules/qt_webkit_version.pri:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/dwarf2.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/debug.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/default_post.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/x86_64.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/objective_c.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/qt.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/moc.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/rez.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/uic.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf:
qmake:  FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -spec ../../../QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/mkspecs/macx-g++ -o Makefile NitePointViewer.pro

dist: 
    @$(CHK_DIR_EXISTS) .tmp/NitePointViewer1.0.0 || $(MKDIR) .tmp/NitePointViewer1.0.0 
    $(COPY_FILE) --parents $(SOURCES) $(DIST) .tmp/NitePointViewer1.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents GL/wglext.h GL/glut.h GL/glext.h GL/gl.h GLES/gl.h GLES/gl_1_0.h GLES/egltypes.h GLES/egl.h GLES/egl_1_0.h glh/glh_text.h glh/glh_obs.h glh/glh_mipmaps.h glh/glh_linear.h glh/glh_interactors.h glh/glh_glut2.h glh/glh_glut.h glh/glh_glut_text.h glh/glh_glut_replay.h glh/glh_glut_callfunc.h glh/glh_genext.h glh/glh_extensions.h glh/glh_cube_map.h glh/glh_convenience.h glh/glh_array.h signal_catch.h PointDrawer.h opengles.h kbhit.h .tmp/NitePointViewer1.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents main.cpp signal_catch.cpp PointDrawer.cpp kbhit.cpp .tmp/NitePointViewer1.0.0/ && (cd `dirname .tmp/NitePointViewer1.0.0` && $(TAR) NitePointViewer1.0.0.tar NitePointViewer1.0.0 && $(COMPRESS) NitePointViewer1.0.0.tar) && $(MOVE) `dirname .tmp/NitePointViewer1.0.0`/NitePointViewer1.0.0.tar.gz . && $(DEL_FILE) -r .tmp/NitePointViewer1.0.0


clean:compiler_clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(OBJECTS)
    -$(DEL_FILE) *~ core *.core


####### Sub-libraries

distclean: clean
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(TARGET) 
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile


check: first

mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all

compiler_objective_c_make_all:
compiler_objective_c_clean:
compiler_moc_header_make_all:
compiler_moc_header_clean:
compiler_rcc_make_all:
compiler_rcc_clean:
compiler_image_collection_make_all: qmake_image_collection.cpp
compiler_image_collection_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) qmake_image_collection.cpp
compiler_moc_source_make_all:
compiler_moc_source_clean:
compiler_rez_source_make_all:
compiler_rez_source_clean:
compiler_uic_make_all:
compiler_uic_clean:
compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
compiler_lex_make_all:
compiler_lex_clean:
compiler_clean: 

####### Compile

main.o: main.cpp PointDrawer.h \
        GL/glut.h \
        GL/gl.h \
        GL/glext.h \
        opengles.h \
        GLES/gl.h \
        GLES/egl.h \
        GLES/egltypes.h \
        kbhit.h \
        signal_catch.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o main.cpp

signal_catch.o: signal_catch.cpp signal_catch.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o signal_catch.o signal_catch.cpp

PointDrawer.o: PointDrawer.cpp PointDrawer.h \
        GL/glut.h \
        GL/gl.h \
        GL/glext.h \
        opengles.h \
        GLES/gl.h \
        GLES/egl.h \
        GLES/egltypes.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o PointDrawer.o PointDrawer.cpp

kbhit.o: kbhit.cpp kbhit.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o kbhit.o kbhit.cpp

####### Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:
```

Also in main.cpp and PointDrawer.cpp I've added:

```
#define USE_GLUT
```

Comment: thanks you for answer. Thank your for answers.
I already installed freeglut3-dev and included the libraries <GLUT/glut.h> and <GL/glut.h>.
The problem occurs when making the link as you said.
Is there any compiler options for the linkage to succeed?
How to add compiler options in the makefile so it can find where is the GLU library?

Comment: Since you're using freeglut3-dev I'm assuming you're using Ubuntu. You can try `LIBS = -lglut` or `LIBS = -L/path/to/your/freeglut3-dev`, but that's from the top of my head, can't test on Ubuntu now